# Formulário de cadastro

Tags: php, html5, css3

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastros e não sei como proceder nesse caso:

O formulário tem campos obrigatórios, caso o usuário clique em "ok" sem um desses campos estarem preenchidos, volta uma mensagem pedindo para o usuário preencher o formulário. Até aí tudo bem. Só que depois que retorna ao formulário, os campos ficam em brancos novamente, eu gostaria que quando retornasse com a mensagem de erro, os dados que o usuário tinha preenchido anteriormente continuassem preenchidos

Comment: Poste seu código para facilitar a solução.

Comment: Explique melhor como vc está fazendo. Ao preencher o formulário, o usuário é submetido pra outra página e retorna ou é tudo numa página só?

Comment: Porque não está usando javascript para verificar antes de mandar o formulário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User JAVASCRIPT, vou usar um exemplo de formulário.
Eu fiz um método mais simplificado, usando uma unica variável BOLEAN para dizer se tem algum campo vazio ou não.
Fazendo ela TRUE (valido) por padrão e um condição (IF) para cada campo obrigatório que vai torna-la FALSE (invalido) caso esteja vazio ou nulo.

```js
function validarFormulario(){
 var validado = true;
 var meuform = document.forms['meuformulario'] || document.meuformulario;
 /* Checa cada campo obrigatorio
 * Insira uma IF referente somente a cada campo obrigatorio
 */
 if(meuform.nome.value == "" || meuform.nome.value == null){
  validado = false;
 }
 if(meuform.telefone.value == "" || meuform.telefone.value == null){
  validado = false;
 }

 /* informa se qualquer estiver errado ou envia o formulario */
 if(validado == false){
  alert("Preencha os campos obrigatórios");
 }else{
  meuform.submit();
 }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" name="meuformulario">
<p>* Nome:<input type="text" value=""  name="nome" /></p>
<p>* Telefone:<input type="text" value=""  name="telefone" /></p>
<p>Apelido:<input type="text" value=""  name="apelido" /></p>
<p><input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="validarFormulario()" /></p>
</form>
<p>Campos com "*" são obrigatórios.</p>
```

Agora se realmente você quiser que o PHP retorne preencido os valores anteriores após validar e de o erro por falta de preenchimento basta inserir com as variaveis Globais do método POST os valores do campos:

```
* Nome:<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['nome']?>"  name="nome" />
```

Mas este é um método simples da coisa, eu aconselharia fazer o autopreenchimento com JScript em conjunto com PHP pra manter organizado.

Answer (score 0):

O Html5 possui uma propriedade para os componentes chamada required. O que torna o preenchimento do campo obrigatório. Você pode ver mais disso nesse link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required